# Do I need to memorize reflexive verbs?

Tags: preposition, verb, accusative, reflexive

Short and quick question...maybe...

I have been learning German for a couple of months now and I hit a wall on reflexive verbs now.
Do I need to memorize the most commonly used ones? (about 70)

Isn't this and this the same case ?

- sich ärgern
- sich ärgern über

Aren't they both accusative anyway even without "über"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "need to memorize"; are you talking about some language certificate? People have different goals for learning a language, and without knowing those goals it's difficult to say what you need to do to achieve them. I have about 70 reflexive verbs listed in my notes, gleaned from various television shows, games, etc., so they are in common use. Some are rather tricky, for example *vorstellen* has different meanings depending of whether the accusative or dative pronoun is reflexive.

Comment: Yes, I am aiming for the B2 certificate

Comment: What does this have to do with reflexive verbs?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: _auf etwas sehen_ and _sehen_ also both take the accusative: _Ich sehe den Baum_ bzw. _ich sehe auf den Baum_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to speak German on an acceptable level, you need to know which verbs are proper reflexive verbs and which are transitive verbs that optionally can be used reflexive.

English has transitive verbs that can be used reflexive:

> *transitive:* Walter washes **his car.**
> *reflexive:* Walter washes **himself.**

This works with many German verbs too:

> *transitive:* Walter wäscht **sein Auto.**
> *reflexive:* Walter wäscht **sich.**

Note, that here *"himself"* and *"sich"* have a semantic role: They indicate the thing that is washed.

But German has a class of verbs, which need a mandatory reflexive pronoun that is there just for grammatical reasons, without indicating any semantic role. These words are called *"proper reflexive"* (in German: *»echt reflexiv«*), and in this context that type that also exists in English is called *"pseudo reflexive"* (*»unecht reflexiv«*).

German proper reflexive verbs **MUST** always be used with a reflexive pronoun. This pronoun usually has to be in accusative case:

> correct: Ich erhole **mich.** Ich freue **mich.**
> <sup>*I recover. I'm happy.*</sup>
> wrong: <del>Ich erhole **die Frau.** Ich freue **dich.**</del>
> <sup>*literally, "I recover the woman", "I happy you" but this makes no sense*</sup>
> also wrong: Ich erhole. Ich freue.
> <sup>*(means nothing)*</sup>

So, if you want to tell someone that you recover from an injury, you say this in English with this sentence:

> I am recovering from the injury.

If you want to say the same in German, you **MUST** add a reflexive pronoun in accusative case to the verb. It does not carry any specific meaning. It is part of the verb:

> correct: Ich erhole **mich** von der Verletzung.
> wrong: <del>Ich erhole von der Verletzung.</del>

**So, to answer your question:**
It makes no sense to learn by heart a list of proper reflexive verbs. Nobody will ask you to recite this list. But when you write or speak in German, you have to know for each verb which objects it needs, and reflexive pronouns of proper reflexive verbs are nothing else than such mandatory objects.

---

I said, that most proper reflexive verbs need to have their reflexive pronoun to be in accusative case, but there are at least three verbs which also are proper reflexive verbs but need their reflexive pronoun to be in dative case. All of them also need additional other parts of speech:

> sich etwas aneignen: Ich eigne **mir** Deutschkenntnisse an.
> sich etwas ausdenken: Ich denke **mir** ein Spiel aus.
> sich etwas einbilden: Ich bilde **mir** etwas auf mein Aussehen ein.

---

##### About multiple accusative objects

There are some German verbs that need two accusative objects:

> nennen: Simon nennt **den Taxifahrer einen Idioten.**

- den Taxifahrer = accusative object
- einen Idioten = accusative object

Also:

> abfragen: Der Lehrer fragt **den Schüler die Vokabel** ab.
> fragen: Bitte fragen Sie **das meinen Kollegen.**
> angehen: Das geht **deine Eltern einen Dreck** an.
> kosten: Der Apfel kostet **mich einen Euro.**

and a few more.

Some verbs can have an accusative object and a prepositional object:

> aufklären: Der Arzt klärt **den Patienten über die Behandlung** auf.

- den Patienten = accusative object
- über die Behandlung = prepositional object

Prepositional objects consists of two parts: a preposition and an inner object. The case of the inner object does not depend on the verb (which is from what the case of an object depends normally), but from the preposition. Inner objects of prepositional objects can be dative objects or accusative objects. The preposition *»über«* can have both cases, but when *»über«* is part of a prepositional object, it always needs accusative case. So we have:

- die Behandlung = inner accusative object of a prepositional object.

But also adverbial clauses (adverbiale Bestimmungen) consist of a preposition and an inner object, but now also genitive case is allowed for inner objects, and here *»über«* also lives up to its role as an alternating preposition, because it can go now with an inner object in dative and in accusative case.

All in all this leads to the consequence, that you can have many objects in accusative case in one sentence.

> Martin nennt den Mann ohne einen Grund gegen meinen Willen einen Schwachkopf.

- den Mann = accusative object
- einen Grund = inner accusative object of a prepositional object
- meinen Willen = inner accusative object of a prepositional object
- einen Schwachkopf = accusative object

Reflexive pronouns of proper reflexive verbs are no exception.

> Ich freue mich auf den Abend.

- mich = accusative object (reflexive pronoun of a proper reflexive verb)
- den Abend = inner accusative object of a prepositional object

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this helped a lot

Comment: @Desard: Don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

German is not limited to only one accusative object in a sentence: there are two accusative objects in "sich über x ärgern", "sich" and "x". The "über" indicates what you are annoyed / angry about, and the other accusative object is who is annoyed / angry.

If you say "Ich ärgere mich über x" it's clear who is annoyed (you) and about what (x). If you just say "ich ärgere über x" most people will probably guess that you are annoyed about x. If you just say "ich ärgere x" the meaning changes to "I am making x angry".

As far as to whether you need to memorize the reflexive verbs... depends on what you "need". In most cases you will probably be understood (if only from context), but it's clear that you're not a native speaker.

Comment: 'Ich ärgere über x' is simply wrong and ungramatical (but as you note, probably understood)